# plotting a pareto chart from the cell array below in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a Pareto chart from the cell array below.I am facing issues regarding converting it to a vector to plot a Pareto chart and label each bar by data in the first column

```
data={

    'P0702' 200
    'P0882' 75
    'P0500' 14
    'P0740' 7
    'P0755' 7
    'P0760' 7
    'P0763' 7
    'P0657' 6
    'P0718' 6
    'P0743' 6
    'P0750' 6
    'P0753' 6
    'P1921' 6
    'P0710' 5
    'P0748' 5
    'P0758' 5
    'P0713' 4
    'P0735' 4
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easy, you just need to plot a normal `plot` and a `bar` plot together.

In the normal `plot`, you plot the cumulative sum of your data.

```
for ii=1:size(data,1)
    datanum(ii)=data{ii,2};
    datalabel{ii}=data{ii,1};
end

hold on;

bar(datanum);
plot(1:size(data,1),cumsum(datanum),'r');
set(gca,'Xtick',1:size(data,1));
set(gca,'XtickLabel',datalabel);
```

[image]

**EDIT:** 
I didnt know about the `pareto` function, but I assumed there was none, as `pareto(datanum,datalabel)` gives what you want..........

Comment: Thanks.Can i not use the pareto function directly here ?

Comment: @calib_san see edit. Why did you even ask a question if you have a fucntion to do it?

Comment: Thanks that works .I knew the function existed and i had never used it before and i do not see a lot of examples on it.I was facing issue with the array i was working on and its implementation.

Comment: @calib_san consider accepting my answer if it helped you